# Finding the constant of a PDF

Tags: probability, integration, density-function

Consider the function:

$f_h(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
 h-(2+2h)x+6x^2 & x \in [0,1]\\
 0 & otherwise
 \end{array}\right\}$

Now, I have to determine **one** value for $h$ such that $f_h(x)$ becomes a probability density function. Here, I try to solve the integral for the constant $h$ knowing that the pdf should equal to $1$.

$$\begin{align*}
& 1= \int_{0}^{1} h-(2+2h)x+6x^2 dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} h dx - (2+2h)\int_{0}^{1}x dx + 6\int_{0}^{1} x^2 dx \\
&= h - (2+2h)\frac{1}{2} + 6\frac{1}{3} \\
&= h - (1 + h) + 2\end{align*}$$

This is true for all $h$ as both sides are equal. Does this mean I can freely chose what value $h$ has?

Next, I have to determine the probability of the event $[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]$ for all suitable $h$. My approach would be to calculate the same integral with the bounds of $0$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ (the pdf is $0$ in the interval of $[-\frac{1}{2},0]$). Can I ignore $h$ and simply put $h = 0$?

Answer (score 1):

There is another condition on $f_h$: it must be a nonnegative function.

If you are after finding some $h$ such that $f_h$ is a PDF then - on base of your findings so far - you can check out whether that is indeed the case for e.g. $h=0$ and if the answer is "yes" on that then you are ready.

Unfortunately the answer is "no".

For that observe that $f_0(0.1)<0$.

So there is a next question for you now: for which $h$ is $f_h$ indeed a nonnegative function?

Comment: I actually forgot that condition, thank you for bringing it up. I think plugging in some other value e.g. $h = 1$ would satisfy the condition and result in a valid PDF.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot ignore $h$.  While this is a valid pdf for all $h$ and the integral from $0$ to $1$ does not depend upon $h$, the integral from $0$ to $\frac{1}{2}$ **does** depend upon $h$.  Taking the upper bound on your integral to be $\frac{1}{2}$ rather than $1$ gives $\frac{1}{2}h+ \frac{1}{8}(2+ 2h)+ \frac{1}{8}(2)= \frac{h}{2}+ \frac{1}{4}+ \frac{h}{4}+ \frac{1}{4}= \frac{3h+ 2}{4}$.

Comment: Thank you. Does this mean that the probability of the event $[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]$ is dependent on whatever you plug in for $h$?

Comment: "While this is a valid pdf for all $h$ "... No, that is not true.